# Using WP_Query in functions.php only returning one result

Tags: wordpress

I've written a function in my functions.php file that runs a new WP_Query class to fetch some child pages on my custom page template according to their meta key/value. It's kind of working but it's only returning one result - I know there are more as I had the query running properly on the specific page before I turned it into a function. It returned all the correct results, but as I may need this functionality in several pages I decided to turn it into a function.

Here is my function code…

```
function contact_profiles($args) {

    global $post;

    $output = "";

    $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();

        $output = '<div class="staff-member">'                              
        .'<a href="' . get_the_permalink() . '" title="Get in touch with ' . get_the_title() . '">' . get_the_post_thumbnail() . '</a>'
        .'<h2 class="name"><a href="' . get_the_permalink() . '" title="Get in touch with ' . get_the_title() . '">' . get_the_title() . '</a></h2>'
        .'<h3 class="job-role">' . get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'job_role', true ) . '</h3>'
        .'</div>';

    endwhile;

    wp_reset_postdata();

    return $output;
}
```

and here is how I am calling it in my custom page template…

```
    $myarray = array('meta_key' => 'job_area', 'meta_value' => 'Online', 'post_type' => 'page',);

    echo contact_profiles($myarray);
```

Am I doing something obvious that I shouldn't be? Is the `global $post` bit causing the issue as I'm not sure I should call it from the functions file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most probably you have your posts per page setting to `1` in the back end reading section. If no custom value is passed to a custom query, the default option `get_option( 'posts_per_page' )` is used as value to the `posts_per_page` parameter.

You solution would be to explicitely set `posts_per_page` to a desired amount or to `-1` to get all posts

### EDIT

I have missed this before, your concatenation is wrong.

```
$output = '<div class="staff-member">'
```

should be

```
$output .= '<div class="staff-member">'
```

Here is an updated version of your code

```
function contact_profiles($args) 
{

    $output = "";

    $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();

        $output .= '<div class="staff-member">'                             
        .'<a href="' . get_the_permalink() . '" title="Get in touch with ' . get_the_title() . '">' . get_the_post_thumbnail() . '</a>'
        .'<h2 class="name"><a href="' . get_the_permalink() . '" title="Get in touch with ' . get_the_title() . '">' . get_the_title() . '</a></h2>'
        .'<h3 class="job-role">' . get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'job_role', true ) . '</h3>'
        .'</div>';

    endwhile;

    wp_reset_postdata();

    return $output;
}
```

Comment: Hi Pieter, I thought that might have been the case and already tried that - Adding  'posts_per_page' => -1 into the $args array doesn't make any difference :-(

Comment: Check my update, I have missed something obvious :-)

Comment: Also note, `global $post;` in your context is not necessary

Comment: Thanks Peiter, your updated code has worked :-) From what I can see the `global $post` line is necessary for the get_post_meta line - if I take it out that meta_value doesn't show but if I leave it in it works fine. 

I also managed to get it working by making the $output variable inside the while loop an array and imploding it in the return function. Both seem to achieve the desired result but yours is much neater.

Thanks for your help, much appreciated  :-)

Comment: My pleasure. Strange that removing the `$post` fails the post meta, `$post` isset in the loop via `the_post()`, so there is no need setting it. But anyway, glad it worked out for you. Enjoy :-)